# Get all the modified item from a site

Tags: sharepoint-server, sandbox-solution

I'd like to know a way to have all the modified item from a date in a site.
I'm in a sandbox mode so forget powerShell but the script client will be the good way.

Comment: Try using search results webpart and add the necessary filters.

Answer (score 0):

Execute a search with the following syntax:

```
Path:[the_path_of_the_site] Modified=[the_date_in_YYYY-MM-DD_format]
```

KQL Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911%28v=office.15%29.aspx